# How to check if TLS 1.2 was installed in SQL Server by Cumulative update patch

Tags: sql, ssl, sql-server-2012

I ran Cumulative update 1 on a 2012 SQL Server for the purpose of adding TLS 1.2 feature. How do I check if TLS 1.2 feature has been installed. Currently I don't see anything within regedit.

Comment: I would imagine that a combination of `select @@version` and https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/3135244 should be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for replying Ajeh. I checked with Microsoft and they said that proper Installation of the Patch is the solution. Also I see that the version change of the SQL Server in SSMS is also a way to see that TLS 1.2 feature is added.